# LDAPException size limit exceeded

Tags: ldap, ldap-query, ldapconnection, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I am using unboundid ldap sdk for executing ldap query. I am facing a strange problem while running ldap search query. I am getting a Exception when i run query against a group which contains 50k entries. My Exception :

```
LDAPException(resultCode=4 (size limit exceeded), errorMessage='size limit exceeded')
at com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.migrate.ldapjdk.LDAPSearchResults.nextElement(LDAPSearchResults.java:254)
at com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.migrate.ldapjdk.LDAPSearchResults.next(LDAPSearchResults.java:279)
```

Now the strange thing is i already have set the maxResultSize to 100k in search constrains than why i am getting this error ?
My code is

```
     ld = new LDAPConnection();
    ld.connect(ldapServer, 389);

    LDAPSearchConstraints ldsc = new LDAPSearchConstraints();
    ldsc.setMaxResults(100000);
    ld.setSearchConstraints(ldsc);
```

Anybody have any idea ?

Comment: Which LDAP server vendor?

Answer (score 7):

Sorry for necroposting, but your topic with no answer is still the first in google.

Using **unboundid** you actually can get unlimited number of records in  paging mode.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

try {
    int count = 0;
    LDAPConnection connection = new LDAPConnection("hostname", 389, "user@domain", "password");

    final String path = "OU=Users,DC=org,DC=com";
    String[] attributes = {"SamAccountName","name"};

    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(path, SearchScope.SUB, Filter.createEqualityFilter("objectClass", "person"), attributes);

    ASN1OctetString resumeCookie = null;
    while (true)
    {
        searchRequest.setControls(
                new SimplePagedResultsControl(100, resumeCookie));
        SearchResult searchResult = connection.search(searchRequest);
        for (SearchResultEntry e : searchResult.getSearchEntries())
        {
            if (e.hasAttribute("SamAccountName"))
                System.out.print(count++ + ": " + e.getAttributeValue("SamAccountName"));

            if (e.hasAttribute("name"))
                System.out.println("->" + e.getAttributeValue("name"));
        }

        LDAPTestUtils.assertHasControl(searchResult,
                SimplePagedResultsControl.PAGED_RESULTS_OID);
        SimplePagedResultsControl responseControl =
                SimplePagedResultsControl.get(searchResult);
        if (responseControl.moreResultsToReturn())
        {
            resumeCookie = responseControl.getCookie();
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }


}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Check the server-side size limit setting.  It prevails over the client-side setting which is what you're doing in your code.