# java ldapsearchexception size limit exceeded setMaxResults

Tags: java, size, limit, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I get this error: `"LDAPSearchException: size limit exceeded" error` and the server is only returning 500 results. I am assured by our highly experienced LDAP administrator that this limit is not set on the server. Indeed I can get much more than 500 results by using 'ldapsearch' on the CLI.

The suggestion in this article [LDAPException Size Limit exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169425/ldapexception-size-limit-exceeded) is exactly what I need. However when I try to set the LDAPSearchConstraints object on my LDAPConnection object (`ld.setSearchConstraints(ldsc);`) I get a compile error saying the method doesn't exist:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : method setSearchConstraints(com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.migrate.ldapjdk.LDAPSearchConstraints)
location: class com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPConnection.
```

Does someone know why this method is not available? I have tried different versions of `unboundid-ldapsdk` and even tried different repositories in my pom file. Alternatively, if someone knows how to retrieve more than the default search results using a different approach please let me know.

I am using 64 bit linux (version: "3.2.0-4-amd64") and Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-8)
Java version: 1.6.0_31

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After taking a look at the [API](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldapsdk/docs/javadoc), the correct way to limit the search results is

```
com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPConnection connection = <some connection>

com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest(<your parameters>);
request.setSizeLimit(<your limit>);

SearchResult result = connection.search(request);
```

The compilation error occurs because you are importing the wrong LDAPConnection.

[com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.migrate.ldapjdk.LDAPConnection](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldapsdk/docs/javadoc/com/unboundid/ldap/sdk/migrate/ldapjdk/LDAPConnection.html) <-- supports [setSearchConstraints](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldapsdk/docs/javadoc/com/unboundid/ldap/sdk/migrate/ldapjdk/LDAPConnection.html#setSearchConstraints%28com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.migrate.ldapjdk.LDAPSearchConstraints%29)

[com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPConnection](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldapsdk/docs/javadoc/com/unboundid/ldap/sdk/LDAPConnection.html) <-- you are using this class, which doesn't support `setSearchConstraints`