# Fetching more than 1000 rows from Domino LDAP server using .NET Core 5 and Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ldap, lotus-domino, .net-5

I want to fetch all the users from a large location of our Domino LDAP, around ~2000 users altogether. Since .NET Core sadly doesn't have a platform independent LDAP library, I'm using [Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard](https://github.com/dsbenghe/Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard) with this POC:

```
var cn = new Novell.Directory.Ldap.LdapConnection();
cn.Connect("dc.internal", 389);
cn.Bind("user", "pw");
string filter = "location=MyLoc";
var result = cn.Search("", Novell.Directory.Ldap.LdapConnection.ScopeOne, filter, new string[] { Novell.Directory.Ldap.LdapConnection.AllUserAttrs }, typesOnly: false);            
int count = 0;
while (result.HasMore()) {
    var entry = result.Next();
    count++;
    Console.WriteLine(entry.Dn);
}
```

It prints me a lot of entries, but not all. When `count = 1000` I got an `Size Limit Exceeded` exception. I guess this is because I need to use some kind of pagination, so not all entries woult be returned in a single request. There are different questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58461921/how-to-do-a-paged-search-on-an-ldap-server-with-10000-entries-using-novell-dir) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169425/ldapexception-size-limit-exceeded). Both in Java, the .NET Core API seems somehow different.

### Approach 1: Try to find out how `LdapSearchRequest` works in .NET Core

```
byte[] resumeCookie = null;
LdapMessageQueue queue = null;
var searchReq = new LdapSearchRequest("", LdapConnection.ScopeOne, filter, new string[] { LdapConnection.AllUserAttrs },
LdapSearchConstraints.DerefNever, maxResults: 3000, serverTimeLimit: 0, typesOnly: false, new LdapControl[] { new SimplePagedResultsControl(size: 100, resumeCookie) });            
var searchRequest = cn.SendRequest(searchReq, queue);
```

I'm trying to figure out how the Java examples can be used in .NET Core. This looks good, however I can't figure out how to fetch the LDAP entries. I only get an message id. [By looking into the source](https://github.com/dsbenghe/Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard/blob/master/src/Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard/LdapConnection.cs#L2132) it seems that I'm on the right way, but they're using `MessageAgent` which cannot be used outside since it's `internal sealed`. This is propably the reason why searching for `LdapRearchRequest` in the source code doesn't give many results.

### Approach 2: Using `SimplePagedResultsControlHandler`

```
var opts = new SearchOptions("", LdapConnection.ScopeOne, filter, new string[] { LdapConnection.AllUserAttrs });
// For testing purpose: https://github.com/dsbenghe/Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard/issues/163
cn.SearchConstraints.ReferralFollowing = false;
var pageControlHandler = new SimplePagedResultsControlHandler(cn);
var rows = pageControlHandler.SearchWithSimplePaging(opts, pageSize: 100);
```

This throws a `Unavaliable Cricital Extension` exception. First I thought that this is an issue of the .NET port, which may doesn't support all the features of the original Java library yet. It seems complete and according to further researches, it looks like to be an LDAP error code. So this must be something which has to be supported by the server, but is not supported by Domino.

Comment: Approach 2 seems good to me but yes it seems domino does not support RFC-2696 which defines the extension, @see [RFCs supported by the LDAP service](https://help.hcltechsw.com/domino/10.0.1/admin/conf_rfcssupportedbytheldapservice_c.html).

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't make at least one of those approachs work, but found another way: Cross platform support for the [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.protocols?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) namespace was  [was added in .NET 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-0/#expanding-system-directoryservices-protocols-to-linux-and-macos). This was missing for a long time in .NET Core and I guess this is the main reason why libraries like `Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard` were ported to .NET Core - in times of .NET Core 1.x this was the only way I found to authenticate against LDAP wich works on Linux too.

After having a deeper look into `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols`, it works well out of the box, even for ~2k users. My basic POC class looks like this:

```
public class DominoLdapManager {
    LdapConnection cn = null;
    public DominoLdapManager(string ldapHost, int ldapPort, string ldapBindUser, string ldapBindPassword) {
        var server = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(ldapHost, ldapPort);
        var credentials = new NetworkCredential(ldapBindUser, ldapBindPassword);

        cn = new LdapConnection(server);
        cn.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
        cn.Bind(credentials);
    }
    public IEnumerable<DominoUser> Search(string filter, string searchBase = "") {
        string[] attributes = { "cn", "mail", "companyname", "location" };
        var req = new SearchRequest(searchBase, filter, SearchScope.Subtree, attributes);
        var resp = (SearchResponse)cn.SendRequest(req);

        foreach (SearchResultEntry entry in resp.Entries) {
            var user = new DominoUser() {
                Name = GetStringAttribute(entry, "cn"),
                Mail = GetStringAttribute(entry, "mail"),
                Company = GetStringAttribute(entry, "companyname"),
                Location = GetStringAttribute(entry, "location")
            };
            yield return user;
        }
        yield break;
    }
    string GetStringAttribute(SearchResultEntry entry, string key) {
        if (!entry.Attributes.Contains(key)) {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        string[] rawVal = (string[])entry.Attributes[key].GetValues(typeof(string));
        return rawVal[0];
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
var ldapManager = new DominoLdapManager("ldap.host", 389, "binduser", "pw");
var users = ldapManager.Search("objectClass=person");
```

### But it's not solved with `Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard` as the title said

This doesn't solve my problem with the `Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard` library as the title suggested, yes. But since `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols` is a official .NET package maintained by Microsoft and the .NET foundation, this seems the better aproach for me. The foundation will take care to keep it maintained and compatible with further .NET releases. When I wrote the question, I was not aware of the fact that Linux support is added now.

Don't get me wrong, I don't want to say that third packages are bad by design - that would be completely wrong. However, when I have the choice between a official package and a third party one, I think it makes sense to prefer the official one. Except there would be a good reason against that - which is not the case here: The official package (which doesn't exist in the past) works better to solve this issue than the third party one.